# How to Calculate Clock Rate for Processor?

Tags: computer-architecture, cache

Please can anyone help me to solve the following question, I have no idea to solve that .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks. Hope answer will help someone 
[image]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).

Comment: Yh, understood that